# Conky moving back and forth, seemingly randomly

Tags: conky

I've been using this really nice, slightly modified Gotham `.conkyrc` for a while, and lately, the window has been jiggling. It stays still in conky-manager, but I don't want to use it, so I copied the rc file into `~/.conkyrc` and it's been moving back and forth, every time it redraws. I have no clue why, and googling has only yielded results on how to *move* it, not to make it stop.

Here's the `.conkyrc` that I'm using right now, I'll answer any questions for further detail.

```
use_xft true
xftfont 123:size=8
xftalpha 0.1
update_interval 0.1
total_run_times 0

own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_colour 000000
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 0

double_buffer yes
#minimum_size 250 5
#maximum_width 500
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
default_color white
default_shade_color red
default_outline_color green
alignment top_right
gap_x 0
gap_y 0
no_buffers yes
uppercase no
cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 1
override_utf8_locale yes
use_spacer right

color1 F4A
color2 39F
color3 FFA300
color4 2C4

#color1 fff
#color2 fff
#color4 fff

minimum_size 0 200

TEXT
${voffset 10}${color1}${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=120}${time %I:%M %P}${font}${voffset -84}${offset 10}${color3}${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=42}${time %d} ${voffset -15}${color2}${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=22}${time  %B} ${time %Y}${font}${voffset 24}${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=58}${offset -148}${time %A}${font}
${voffset 1}${offset 12}${font Ubuntu:pixelsize=12}${color3}HD ${offset 9}${color4}${fs_free /} / ${fs_size /}${offset 30}${color3}RAM ${offset 9}${color4}$mem / $memmax${offset 30}${color3}CPU ${offset 9}${color4}${cpu cpu0}% ${goto 410}${cpu cpu1}% ${goto 440}${cpu cpu2}%${goto 480}${color3}BTRY${offset 9}${color4}${battery}${goto 45}${voffset 15}$color4${fs_bar 10, 100}${goto 215}${membar 10, 95}${goto 372}${voffset -5}${cpugraph 15, 30 -t}${cpugraph cpu1 15, 30 -t}${cpugraph cpu2 15, 30 -t}${voffset 5}${goto 517}${battery_bar 10, 105}
```

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and it looks like this:
[image: Conky screenchot]

Answer (score 0):

You would probably get better answers in Ubuntu Forums, Cafe, Conky sub section but I would start by commenting out line:

```
#override_utf8_locale yes
```

If that doesn't work I would change:

```
draw_shades yes
default_shade_color 000000
```

Lastly I would change:

```
minimum_size 200 
maximum_width 400
```

If the last change fixes it but the size is wrong, tweak the values.

Other than that I can't see much difference between your broken Conky and my own Conky configuration which works fine (Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04).

I did copy your `TEXT` section into my own and it paints okay without "moving back and forth". You wouldn't want my whole configuration though because it's ugly code of various experiments.

Comment: Edited. I'll try your fixes as soon as I can, thanks in advance!